# Making two AutoHotkey key remapping scripts work together correctly

Tags: autohotkey

I have two AutoHotkey scripts that enable the use of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on both sides of my laptop's keyboard:

1. Map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to (left) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

   ```
   SetCapsLockState, Off
   CapsLock::LCtrl
   ```
2. Map <kbd>Enter</kbd> to (right) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when pressed down; otherwise (if no timeout) send <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   Enter::RCtrl
   ~Enter Up::Send % "{RCtrl up}" (A_PriorKey = "Enter" ? "{Enter}" : "")
   ```

The two scripts work perfectly with almost no edge cases.

However, I'm unable to trigger <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which is a shortcut that I usually use to open a new line on my text editor. Pressing down <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing happens. Even if I press down (left)<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (the real key) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing happens as well.

What should I do to enable both scripts to work together in order to enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem in two steps:

1. Natively map CapsLock to Control. AutoHotkey thinks my CapsLock key is indeed the Control key, which exempts me from handling weird CapsLock on/off edge cases within AutoHotkey.
2. Use the following script to map Enter as dual-function RCtrl/Enter:

```
LShift & Enter Up::
  GetKeyState, state, Shift
  if (A_PriorKey = "Enter" and state = "D") {
    Send +{Enter}
  }
  Send {LCtrl Up}{RCtrl Up}
  Return
LCtrl & Enter Up::
  GetKeyState, state, Control
  if (A_PriorKey = "Enter" and state = "D") {
    Send ^{Enter}
  }
  Send {LCtrl Up}{RCtrl Up}
  Return
LAlt & Enter Up::
  GetKeyState, state, Alt
  if (A_PriorKey = "Enter" and state = "D") {
    Send !{Enter}
  }
  Send {LCtrl Up}{RCtrl Up}
  Send {LAlt Up}{RAlt Up}
  Return
Enter::RCtrl
~Enter Up::
  Send % "{RCtrl up}" ((A_PriorKey = "Enter") ? "{Enter}" : "")
```

It's super exciting because it works very well! The modifier dance between CapsLock and Enter as symmetric control keys is perfect and I can seamlessly alternate between both sides without nasty edge cases, unexpected modifier presses, releases, or `{Enter}` presses. The order of the declarations is very important for that to work; the edge cases must come first.

However, as you can see, it is necessary to explicitly handle <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If I ever need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I will need to handle that as well.

I wonder if there's a better way to make that work without having to define these additional mappings.

Answer (score 1):

I've tryied on Libreoffice Writter, where CTRL+ENTER go to the next page..
The above code worked fine.
Just added ~ before `Enter::RCtrl` to not block native function from Enter key.

```
SetCapsLockState, Off
CapsLock::LCtrl
~Enter::RCtrl
~Enter Up:: Send % "{RCtrl up}" (A_PriorKey = "Enter" ? "{Enter}" : "")
```

P.S:
And i think you may use only one script with both instructions, instead of using one script for each..

Comment: Thank you so much Dieisson, but that does not work. Holding down Enter sends `{Enter}` and then activates the `{Ctrl}` modifier. That is not quite what I want. To activate `{Enter}`, I want a quick press and release of the Enter key, which my original script handles very well.